# opencv find block of text areas / detect document layout

Tags: java, python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have color image document with text and images and tables.
Document can have two columns.
Document is composite from areas: area header and text (bigger font, can have different font color and something like sub-header additional data).

This is exemplary image but real one can be color:
[image]

What i need to do.
I need find on image document this areas of text with headers.
What i need to know.
Method how to divide document to divide document on particular parts.

I try with opencv in java(if someone have python and c++ version i can convert it for java version by myself). I found few similar problem on stack overflow, but none of them can help me. You must know that my opencv knowledge is not very well and it is only from on-line tutorials and stack overflow.

Is there any fine solution on my problem in opencv way or i need use something else, different library or application to achieve this?

One and only requirement is that it must be done from command line.

If i had this areas i can do what i need next, but this is step which stops me.

Comment: Can you post some more sample images? This will give us an idea of the different formats that you are trying to accommodate in the solution.

Comment: @ravjanisz can you point me to the name of the image annotation tool shown in the picture please ?

Answer (score 0):

have you solved the problem?

I'm working on a similar problem.
My solution is to use  [`HoughLines`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use text detection combined with dilation to detect bold text i.e. headers and then group the text boxes between two consecutive headers as the text under first header.